# TensorFlow learning after finishing tutorials

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I have finished almost all of the official tutorials of TensorFlow
,and understood basic way to make TensorFlow machine-learning model.
Then, what should I do to improve my TensorFlow skills.
I want to make a model like predict results of a sport.

Answer (score 0):

*(Shameless self promotion)*

I wanted to develop my day-to-day skills in Tensorflow and get a better natural feel for it and searched for something like [nodeschool](https://nodeschool.io/#workshoppers) but for Tensorflow but I couldn't find one, so I wrote [learn-to-tensorflow](https://github.com/panchishin/learn-to-tensorflow)

It is a graduated set of challenges, starting with a super easy challenge of counting to 10.  There are also different levels for each challenge, *such as with or without template code*.

This will not make give you a PhD in ML but what it will do is build skills and know-how.

When I put together the challenges I was barely able to create them.  Finally after practicing for 3 weeks I was able to accomplish level 4 on all the challenges.  It was tough, but now working on tensorflow problems feels super natural and flows.  Now when I work on a larger project debugging is so much easier.